# JavaScript/jQuery for state and country input

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

Is there some nice jQuery way of handling country and territory input in forms, while keeping validation in Django?

For instance, if I select "United States," populate the territory select with the states, with   Spain disable the territory box, etc. Is there a library or plugin that provides this which I could also integrate with Django validation?

Answer (score 0):

You used 'django' tag in the *tags'* part your question. So the plugin must be a part of django project.

At least the one plugin (you asked about a 'way', not obligatorily a 'plugin') we have: http://code.google.com/p/django-worlddb/